samba authentication working with linux credentials on server but not on share with samba credentials
I can connect to the samba server with my Linux user credentials on Windows explorer, but not to the following share:
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /home/leder/consume
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = no
    read only = no
    create mask = 0644
    writeable = yes
    directory mask = 0755
    valid users = smbuser
    force user = smbuser

...neither with the linux passwd nor with the smbpasswd.
What I have already tried:

add samba user/password and enable it both for linux user and for smbuser
restart smbd.service

I am clueless!

somehow it worked out, I do not know what was the resolving fact. What I tried out was the following:

map network drive for samba share
use samba credentials for existing linux user not smbuser
reboot windows machine
reauthenticate step 2)

